# How do you provide different declarations of a class for different iOS versions?

Tags: ios, attributes, version

My app needs to target iOS 12, but use features from iOS 13 when they're available (notably menus for Catalyst).

I've marked my AppDelegate as available in iOS 13+ with the @available attribute; I think I saw this as a solution on another post here. But my app crashes on iOS 12 because it still calls an iOS 13 function that's not available in iOS 12 (UIWindow's overrideUserInterfaceStyle). This seems like a bug, but then... why does the app even launch under iOS 12, when I've marked its entire delegate as iOS 13+ only?

And what's the correct way to provide an alternate definition of the class for pre-iOS 13 versions? If I create another declaration in the same file but mark it with @available(iOS 12, *), the compiler complains about the duplicate definition.

[image]

I can mark each offending method with @available instead of the whole class, but this breaks down when you encounter a stored property of a type that's not available in the older OS version; the compiler complains that you can't make a stored property potentially nonexistent by putting @available on it.

Comment: Don't mark the whole class. You need to guard the specific iOS 13 code with #if

Comment: Thanks, but you can't use that on method declarations. So if the declaration takes a parameter type that doesn't exist in the earlier OS (for example, UIMenuBuilder), it won't build.

Comment: It is a bit ugly but you cloud create a model object and then subclass that object, putting the iOS13 properties in the subclass. You would then need to use `#if available` and down casting on your model object to access those properties.

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks. For now I ended up removing the @ available from the class, using #available for one call, and then putting @ available on all the offending methods. This still left a stored property that couldn't be tagged with @ available, but fortunately that was a custom class; so I went into it and flagged every method with @ available.